Some letters shows like numbers
I have sony vaio, with ubuntu 22.4 mate
if I press m it shows 0  
if I press u it shows 4  

and few others letter
THIS TEXT WAS WRITTEN WITH ONBOARD,Please help

Judging from which numbers are being displayed when pressing each key, you most likely have one of those "virtual numpads" that ship with some laptops enabled, or a jammed Fn key.

How to go about disabling the "virtual numpad" will depend on the actual laptop; usually you have to press the right Fn + F1-12 combo as shown in the picture (the symbols on the F1-12 keys should give a hint) or Fn + NumLock.
If the Fn key turns out to be jammed, you can look into disabling it (I would go with the BIOS solution; if it's jammed, you want to disable it at the hardware level).

Thank you Kos, at my please solution was to disable numlock, which here on vaio is right from F12, and it don't need Fn to be pressed.

I'm glad you fixed it! @josifoski
